# Moving "Product Options" Below Description Tab OpenCart

Tags: opencart

Haloo guys, I'm new here , i have a problem about template,

I want move this product options
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BK4r.png

to bottom of Description tab .

Before, i can move it , but i had a problem , when i moved the product options Below Description Tab, when all required fields filled , then i push button "add to cart" , it said all required fields is Required!

Please help me, Thank you.

Comment: please show the code that you have written

Comment: i have show it in another answear

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/rXPZCYBx

its the product page,

the product option page start from here

```
  <div class="options push-<?php echo $this->journal2->settings->get('product_page_options_push_select'); ?>">
```

i make it back to normal